# Canvas Get Stuck when using fabric.loadSVGFromString

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

When I load SVGs via `fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg)`, the Fabric Canvas gets stuck and ultimately the browser freezes. However, I don't observe any problems when I use `fabric.Image.fromURL(base64Svg)`. However, I can't utilize base64 converted images since the `canvas.toSVG()` function returns an image, which I can't use for image conversion. (In my backend, I use an SVG to JPEG converter.)

Is there a way to resolve this problem? Your assistance is much appreciated.